# Is it possible to build hidden areas / React-Components based on serverside data?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js

We need to build an application where some users are allowed to access some pages, other users are not allowed to. As this ain't enough, we have some components on that pages (buttons, links) which are users not allowed to see.

So we let's say we have different usergroups (lets say a, b and c) which can handle different pages and different page components. May user a is a full admin, which can see all pages and components on the pages. User b is only allowed to access pages and components of a subsection in the project. User c might be a "read-only" user.

The user permissions are stored in a database which was used in jsf before. We want to switch to "2019" instead of keeping "2010 technology". In JSF we stored the information of a users permission in Session-Scoped beans and then we build pages which had components we could render or not (e.g. `<button render=#{user.isallowedto}>`).

Is it possible to do the same in a react application with node backend? Performing a login process with permission-handling in the node backend by using express-session and passport was already successful, but can the information of a user permission also be used in our react frontend?

Any help would be great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: sure. and basically the same idea. eg in some render: `render (){return user.isallowed && (<Button/>) `

Comment: Of course it can, however, React has nothing to do with Node or `express-session`, those are server-side concerns. You would simply return the relevant permissions to the client and then (similar to what you did in JSF) handle with disabling or blocking the relevant pages/components.

Comment: thanks a lot. we got it exactly like this. But what we need is to pass the users permission data **safe** to the client. If you do it by cookies, as far as we understood it, it is possible to change the cookie data. That would lead to the fact, a user could see a page (blank, due to the api security which is server-side handeled)...
Would it be an option to use hashed data in a cooikie?

Answer (score 0):

## frontend protection vs backend protection

### frontend

So on a basic level you can protect the frontend of the app by having something like this

```
import React from 'react';

export function button ({text, action, isAdmin}) {
  if (!isAdmin) return null;

  return <button onClick={(e) => action(e)}>{text}</button>
}
```

where `isAdmin` is something you determine with your session or login with user roll. Your login client should provide this info with a token or user object.

In the above example we return null when there's no admin user, null is a valid return for a react component, it just doesn't render anything.

### backend

The next level of protection comes from your backend. You **NEED** to protect your API server side so even if a hacker changes the `isAdmin` variable client side he still can't access the endpoints that are off limits to non-admin users. But this will be based on your login/auth service and what kind of API you are building.

But if you intend on using node express for example you can check rolls with middleware. Middleware runs on every request a user makes, it's here that you can check if a users login token has admin privileges to access sensitive data.

### conclusion

This is just a high level description of how to approach the problem, I hope it gives you an idea of the different types of protection you need to build into your web apps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast anwer. Basically we understood it exactly that way and our basic conept was just like your idea. Our question is a little more related to the `isAdmin` parameter you mentioned. As we see it, this parameter can be provided by our login procedure, but is client-side stored (for e.g. in a cookie). That would mean, that a user possibly could change this data and see the button. As you mentionned, the API would also be protedted, so a user could possibly change the visibility client-side but he would not access any data. Did we get it right?

Comment: @FabianLinn yes thats correct if the data is protected server side then you shouldn't worry about it. Personally I would store the login token in a cookie or local storage but when a user logs in they will probably get access to some data i.e. name, email, gender, at this point you can add a `role` key to distinguish what access your users have. so when a user logs in they get the roll as data, you can put this in your state mangement tool (redux) and check it for access when rendering components.